# Store QLineEdit's data into a QString upon a QPushButton click

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsscene, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I am new to Qt programming. What I want to do is pretty much self explanatory from the title I guess. I have a lineEdit whose data I want to store in a QString when a cretain PushButton is clicked. The problem is the above widgets are inside a graphicsScene so i dont have a 
    on_pushbutton_clicked();
function.

The code for my own solution is below, but as you might have guessed, its not working.

```
QLineEdit *l = new QLineEdit ;
QPushButton *b = new QPushButton;

QGraphicsProxyWidget *line = scene.addWidget(l);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *button = scene.addWidget(b);

line->setPos(-600,270);
button->setPos(-600,310);
//b->clicked();

QString input;
QString input = l->text(input);


QObject::connect(b,SIGNAL (clicked()),l, SLOT (setText(QString)));
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how putting the widgets inside a QGraphicsScene should make a difference here.

1. Keep a pointer to the QLineEdit "l" in your class, e.g. as QLineEdit* m_lineEdit.
2. connect b, SIGNAL(clicked()) to a slot buttonClicked().
3. Implement buttonClicked like this:

   ```
   void MyWidget::buttonClicked() {
       const QString text = m_lineEdit->text();
       //do something with "text"
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem is that I all these widgets and QGraphicsScene are created inside the main function. So I don't have something like mainwindow::buttonclicked() or dialogue::buttonclicked().

Also I haven't re implemented the QPushButton of which b is an object. b is a default QPushButton so I don't have a 'MyWidget' for which I could implement this function as you mentioned.


    void MyWidget::buttonClicked() {
        const QString text = m_lineEdit->text();
        //do something with "text"
    }

Comment: You'll need some QObject that can be connected to clicked() and knows about the LineEdit and what to do with it. To react to signals in a custom way that's more than connecting an existing signal to an existing slot, there's no other way than to define a slot, and that can only happen in a QObject/QWidget subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I think ill have to create my own custom widget to solve this slot and signals problem !