# Convert data from QLineEdit to QString when a QPushButton is clicked.

Tags: c++, qt4

This site is trully amazing I would like to thanks anyone who answers my post. You would probably find my post a repost of a repost since it's again about retreive data from a QLineEdit. I've been trying to fix the problem for 2 entire days looking throught the hudge stackoverflow database but I can't find a answer.

Basically I want to retreive an ip address from a QLineEdit and a port number from a QLineEdit to do so I do :

```
myclass::myclass(QWidget *parent = 0)
{
     _mainuilayout = new QGridLayout();
     ipAddress = new QLineEdit();
     portnumber = new QLineEdit();
     QFormLayout *connect2adress = new QFormLayout();
     connect2adress->addRow("Ip Adress : ", ipAddress);
     connect2adress->addRow("Port number : ", portnumber);
     _launch = new QPushButton("Launch server");
     _mainuilayout->addWidget(_launch);
     _mainuilayout->addLayout(connect2adress);

     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setipAddress()));
     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setportnumber()));

     server->connectTo(thisaddress,thisport);

     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), server, SLOT(launchserver()));
}
```

Here you got the code to store the ip address in a QString thisaddress is a QString defined in the header as well as thisport

```
void myclass::setipAddress()
{
     thisaddress = ipAddress->text();
}

void myclass::setportnumber()
{
    thisport = portnumber->text().toShort();
}
```

What I want is when I click on launch button it store the data from QLineEdit in thisaddress and in thisport so I can launch the server, here is the code for connectTo

```
void server::connectTo(QString ipAdress,quint16 port)
{
    if(!ipAdress.isEmpty() && port != 0 )
    {
         ipAddress = ipAdress;
         portnumber = port;
    }
}
```

The problem is really coming when I convert QLineEdit to QString because when I directly assign thisAddress and thisportnumber like that it's working

```
  thisAddress = "127.0.0.1"
  thisportnumber = 5855
```

Overwise I got this error :

```
  Unsupported socket Operation
```

So guys do you have any answers to help me ?
I've tried to follow the solution given in that stack post [Store QLineEdit's data into a QString upon a QPushButton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903689/store-qlineedits-data-into-a-qstring-upon-a-qpushbutton-click) 
but it still not working I'm still working on it if I find something I let you know !
Thanks for the replies !

Comment: I guess the problem is in calling "server->connectTo(thisaddress,thisport);" bit too early (that too in a constructor)? Ideally, you would call it only when server::ipAddress & server::portnumber holds right data.

Answer (score 1):

It has been ages since I used Qt, but I see nobody has answered your question so I'll add my two cents.

I don't think you can expect a specific call order when you connect an event to multiple slots.  You are connecting `clicked()` event on the `_launch` button to populate your IP address and port number, and also to call `launchserver()`.  But you require the other two slots to be called first.

It would be better if you can just connect it to a single slot, which will update the appropriate member values and *then* do the connect.

Comment: Yeah I try what you just said paddy thanks. Arun you said something really interesting. Basically when do I know that QLineEdit stored something. I've read here http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41680-QLineEdit-text-not-retrieved that you have to give time to QLineEdit to get the data. but how ???? It's that I don't understand how can I be sure that QLineEdit has been filled ???? How much do I need to wait ???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm either missing something, or there is confusion about what exactly is happening in the connect calls.  The connect function only tells Qt what to do when a signal is emitted (usually when the user does something).  It does not wait for that event to happen.

```
myclass::myclass(QWidget *parent = 0)
{
     // <snipped construction and layout>

     // Tell Qt what to do when the clicked signal happens:
     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setipAddress()));
     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setportnumber()));

     // At this point, nothing has been set, because the user hasn't had time to
     // fill in anything -- you've only told the application what to do when they
     // do so.
     server->connectTo(thisaddress,thisport);

     // As pointed out previously, even though you're telling the application what
     // to do, the application says nothing about the order, so you don't know if
     // this will be run before or after the slots to set the ip address and port
     // number.
     // What you do know is that it won't be run before the previous line of code,
     // which does the first connection.
     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), server, SLOT(launchserver()));
}
```

The following is a more straightforward implementation:

```
myclass::myclass(QWidget *parent = 0)
{
     _mainuilayout = new QGridLayout();
     _ipAddress = new QLineEdit();
     _portnumber = new QLineEdit();
     QFormLayout *connect2adress = new QFormLayout();
     connect2adress->addRow("Ip Adress : ", ipAddress);
     connect2adress->addRow("Port number : ", portnumber);
     _launch = new QPushButton("Launch server");
     _mainuilayout->addWidget(_launch);
     _mainuilayout->addLayout(connect2adress);

     QObject::connect(_launch, SIGNAL(clicked()), server, SLOT(launchserver()));
}

myclass::launchserver()
{
     server->connectTo(_ipAddress->text(),_portnumber->text().toShort());    
}
```

Comment: TTHHHAAAAAAAAANNNKKKSSSS a lot Caleb Huitt it worked ! Thanks a lot ! I didnt understand how it is working. Basically when I want to retreive the data from a QLineEdit I have to use a slot ?

Comment: I'm glad I could help (and if this was indeed the solution, there is a checkmark beside the answer you can use to mark it solved [and give me bit of credit]).  You don't have to use a slot to retrieve the data, but in this case, you wanted to use the data when the user clicked a button, so the slot is for the button click. In the slot, you retrieve the data, yes, but you could just as easily do it anywhere else.